# function using fopen() keeps opening the same file, even if given different filenames as parameters

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to open multiple files sequentially, using fopen(), just printing the contents and counting the chars. 
In main() I call the function twice using different filenames but the function just prints the contents of the **first** file **twice**. Both files do exist, of course, and just calling this function once does print the correct contents; tested with both files. There just seems to be a problem when calling the function multiple times.

Can somebody please give me a hint? What could be wrong?

My function:

```
void open_and_read(char file_name[80]){     
    char c;
    int buf_length = 16384;
    char buf[buf_length];
    char* buf_pointer;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer = fopen(file_name,"r");
    buf_pointer = buf;
    if(file_pointer==NULL){
        printf("Error: File %s not opened!", file_name);
    }
    else {
        while(c!=EOF && i<(buf_length-1)){
            c = fgetc(file_pointer);
            *buf_pointer = c;
            buf_pointer++;
            i++;
        } 
        buf_pointer--;
        *buf_pointer = 0;
        printf("The file %s contains the follwing: \n%s", file_name, buf);
        printf("char-count: %i\n", i);
    }
    if(fclose(file_pointer)!=0){
        printf("File was not closed!");
    }
    else {
        printf("File was successfully closed!"); 
    }
}
```

main():

```
int main(){
    open_and_read("/home/x201/dev/IB/data/line1.dat");
    open_and_read("/home/x201/dev/IB/data/line2.dat");
```

Comment: Are you sure the second file is not empty ?

Comment: initialize char c , and chage type char to int.

Comment: Have you confirmed the `file_name` is as expected before the second fopen? Have you confirmed the return code from `fopen` is non-zero in both calls?

Comment: Yes, they both contain multiple lines of small integers.

Comment: char buf[16384]; is a lot wasted Stack-Space. malloc() and free() is more expandable (threadwise and so)

Comment: malloc() and free() is of course better! I'll implement them later, I was just trying to get the function to open and read my files correctly first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char c;
```

This is not initialised anywhere. Try `char c = '\0'` .

**Edit**:

It would be much appropriate if you would use

```
   while(((c = fgetc(file_pointer))!= EOF) && i<(buf_length-1))
```

There won't be any need to initialise `c`. You will receive its value from `fgetc` itself 
before you enter the loop for the 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

if your file is empty, your "buf_pointer--;" will point to SOMETHING;

Answer (score 0):

Use char c ='\0';

as char c is not initialized so as auto variable it will contain garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is of char variable "c".
Which will be `EOF` while calling the function `open_and_read` second time and it will not go inside the while loop and the contains of the sencond file will not be read and displayed the previous file contains.

solution to this is :-

> char c='\0'